# Path Integral for Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: mathematical-physics, path-integral, stochastic-processes

As per [Wio](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9814447994), the special case of the Fokker-Planck equation (in SDE form)
\begin{equation*}
    dX = f(x)dt + \sqrt{2D} dW_t
\end{equation*}

has the path integral representation in the Ito scheme as
\begin{equation*}
    P(x,t|x_0,t_0) = \int \mathcal{D}(x) e^{-\int^t_{t_0}\mathcal{L}[x(s),\dot{x}(s)]}
\end{equation*}

where
\begin{equation*}
    \mathcal{L}[x(s),\dot{x}(s)] = \frac{(\dot{x} - f(x))^2}{4D} \qquad\qquad\qquad \mathcal{D}(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \prod^n_{i=1} \frac{dx_i}{\sqrt{4\pi D dt}}
\end{equation*}

I wished to generalize this to the full Fokker-Planck equation (in SDE form)
\begin{equation*}
    dX = f(x,t)dt + g(x,t) dW_t
\end{equation*}

However, if I follow the same procedure as in Wio, I face some problems in doing so, which I describe below.

Firstly, let us take $F = \frac{1}{g}, G = -\frac{f}{g}$ for notational simplicity. Then, discretising the SDE as per the Ito scheme, we get
\begin{equation*}
    W_i - W_{i-1} = F(x_{i-1},t_{i-1})(x_i-x_{i-1}) + G(x_{i-1},t_{i-1})(t_i - t_{i-1})
\end{equation*}

Now, we have the solution for the motion of free Brownian particle, for a finite product
\begin{equation*}
    P(W,t|x_0,t_0) = \int \frac{dW_1\cdots dW_n}{(4D\pi dt)^{\frac{n}{2}}}  e^{-L} \qquad\qquad\qquad L = \sum \frac{(W_i - W_{i-1})^2}{4D(t_i - t_{i-1})}
\end{equation*}

Let us perform a change of variables from $W_i$ to $X_i$, as per the above discretisation of the SDE. I have no problems do this to $L$, and it becomes
\begin{equation*}
    L = \frac{1}{4D}\int_{t_0}^t dt\ \left(\frac{\dot{x} - f(x,t)}{g(x,t)}\right)^2
\end{equation*}

However, it is in $\mathcal{D}(x)$ where I face problems. Firstly, we have the Jacobian matrix for the n-variable transformation $W_1, \cdots, W_n \to x_1, \dots, x_n$ as
\begin{equation*}
    J = \left[\frac{\partial W_i}{\partial x_j}\right]
\end{equation*}

From the expression of $W_i$, we can easily see that it becomes a triangular matrix, and so we have
\begin{equation*}
    |J| = \prod^n_{i=1} \frac{\partial W_i}{\partial x_i} = \prod^n_{i=1} F(x_{i-1},t_{i-1})
\end{equation*}

Thus, we have
\begin{equation*}
    \mathcal{D}(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \prod^n_{i=1} \frac{dW_i}{\sqrt{4\pi D dt}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \prod^n_{i=1} \frac{F(x_{i-1},t_{i-1})\ dx_i}{\sqrt{4\pi D dt}}
\end{equation*}

However, even though $\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod^n_{i=1} \frac{dW_i}{\sqrt{4\pi D dt}}$ is well-defined, I am unable to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod^n_{i=1} \frac{F(x_{i-1},t_{i-1})\ dx_i}{\sqrt{4\pi D dt}}$ is well-defined.

So, how would one go about showing this?

Comment: What you are trying to do is to derive the [Onsager-Matchlup](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onsager%E2%80%93Machlup_function) functional - the gory details are likely to be found in the books on quantitative finance, but it is worth checking first the Risken's book on FPE and the Kleinert's book on path integrals - both consider this case and give references.